# Como validar un campo de un formulario

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario, donde tengo, por ejemplo un campo nombre. Después tengo un `JavaScript` con lo siguiente:

```
function validarNombre() {
        valor = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        if (valor == null || valor.length == 0 || /^\s+$/.test(valor)) {
            alert('Falta Llenar Nombre');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Ahora bien, en tiempo real, ¿Cómo hago para llamar a esa función ? existe un evento "fuera de foco" (como si el usuario abandona la caja de texto sin completarla) O  tengo que llamar desde el botón `submit` ?

El problema que tengo muchos campos para validar y eso como se maneja ?

Comment: El evento fuera de foco es [onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur) . Por experiencia de usuario sería mejor ir validando en tiempo real los datos de entrada.

Comment: No sé si conoces bootstrap. Creo que te va a encantar la forma de construir formularios, cómo se ven y además puedes incorporar un validator. [Aquí puedes ver al final varios demos de formularios](http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/) trabajando con validación. Intenta llenar el form errónamente y verás lo que ocurre.

Comment: @A.Cedano yo uso Semantic UI... y estaba pensando en migrar todo a bootstrap 4... he visto algunas cosas muy lindas con esa version... aunque todavía esta en etapa beta

Comment: El validator del comentario anterior funciona también con Semantic. Puedes probar el demo seleccionando _Semantic_ en el select de la izquierda, en cualquiera de los formularios que aparecen al final de la página.

Comment: si, lo estaba viendo... graficamente es un poco mas lindo bootstrap... que me recomiendas @A.Cedano ? esperar que salga la version definitiva de bootstrap 4 ? se sabe cuando sale ?

Comment: Ni idea de cuando sale. Pero si piensas usar Bootstrap 4, puedes empezar implementando la v. 3 mientras tanto, no creo que actualizar cuando salga la v. 4 sea demasiado costoso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guiarte de este codigo:

```
<input type="" onfocusout="validate()" name="">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(){
        alert('here')
    }
</script>
```

> Si quieres ahorrar trabajo puedes usar `jquery` y hay un plugin que se llama `jquery validate`, te ahorraras un montón de trabajo.

Comment: genial !!! gracias !!!

Comment: tengo un problema, que cuando por ejemplo cometo un error, el mensaje emergente se queda pegado como que no me deja corregir el error... es como que se queda todo el tiempo chequeando el error... y me bloquea la página literalmente